# Creating transparent text to show gradient color of underlying div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create gradient text with plain HTML and CSS. Something like the text below

Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/ZYYsj/2/). It is self explanatory.

I know how to achieve this in webkit-browsers only. But i need a Cross-browser solution which has backward compatibity till IE8 atleast.

I know how to generate the gradient. That is not an issue. In the fiddle i have only created gradient for webkit browsers but i know how to do it for IE too. My main issue is how can i make the text transparent so it shows me the gradient of the underlying div.

No JS/jQuery solutions please.

**CODE**

HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="width:200px;height:200px"></div>
<div id="div2" style="width:200px;height:200px">CAN YOU SEE THIS? THIS TEXT IS SUPPOSED TO HAVE COLORED GRADIENTS LIKE THE HELLO WORLD TEXT</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(252, 234, 187, 1) 0%, rgba(252, 205, 77, 1) 50%, rgba(248, 181, 0, 1) 51%, rgba(251, 223, 147, 1) 100%);
}
#div1 {
    z-index:-100;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
#div2 {
    z-index:100;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    background: black;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position:absolute;
}
```

**EDIT:** I believe my question is not clear . I Know about gradients. I want my text to be transparent so that the gradient of the div below can be shown on the transparent text.

Something like [this example](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/)

Comment: [This](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/) is something like what i want. But this works only in webkit browsers. Plus this take an image as the background. i want it to be my desired div

Comment: have you tried the `mask-image` property? It's tought for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use SVG, its a little outside the box, but its cross browser compatible and gives you some more options.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/XfHa3/5/)**

```
<svg height="50">
    <linearGradient id="g1" x="0%" y="100%">
        <stop stop-color="blue" offset="0%" />
        <stop stop-color="green" offset="25%" />
        <stop stop-color="yellow" offset="50%" />
        <stop stop-color="orange" offset="75%" />
        <stop stop-color="red" offset="100%" />
    </linearGradient>
    <text font-size="40" fill="url(#g1)">
        <tspan x="10" y="40">Hello World!</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Tested and working in Chrome, Firefox, and IE9

If you've really got your heart set on a cutout effect, it can also be done with SVG.

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/XfHa3/15/)**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="black">
        <svg width="300" height="100">
            <mask id="cutouttext">
                <rect width="280" height="50" x="0" y="15" fill="white" />
                <text x="50%" y="55%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="48">Hello World</text>
            </mask>
            <rect width="280" height="50" x="25" y="15" fill="black" mask="url(#cutouttext)" />
        </svg>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fall back for IE8 and below:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <style>
        .wrap {
            color: #ff0000;
            font-size:48px;
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 10px;
            height: 90px;
        }
        .black {
            background: black;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width:250px;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

The way it looks in modern browsers:
[image]
and how it looks in IE8 and below:
[image]

Documentation:
[MDN SVG Gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients)
[MDN SVG Text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)
[MDN Mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask)

Comment: he needs a gradient solution for IE 8 ....i dont think its  possible with svg nor css gradient..png is the only option if ie 8 is considered

Comment: @apaul34208 If I wanted to make changes explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22782717/using-svg-logo-as-mask

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [background-clip](http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/).
The catch is that you need to use an image, you can't use a css gradient afaik

update:
it's only supported on webkit though..

Comment: Yes, i want this. exactly. However this is a webkit solution only. I want something which will be supported by atleast ie9 & ie10

Comment: Hmm you're right. Sorry about that. This might be useful: http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html but bear in mind it only works on webkit browsers, it uses a fallback for the non-supported browsers.

Comment: If you would have read the articles you would have recognized that it needs the possibility to only make the letters + signs transparent. This is achieved by the Webkit proprietary `-webkit-text-fill-color` property which is not even part of the latest CSS standard. So the answer to your question is: **It is not possible!**

Answer (score 1):

Following trick will only work if your text/content is on solid background.

I'm summarizing points from [this blog post](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect)

1. Put an empty `span` with in the text container, for eg.
    `<h1> <span> </span> This this heading
   </h1>` etc.
2. Embed `background-image [png]` through `css` to this
   `span`
3. And position it absolutely, upon the text.

It works in IE6 onwards, but IE PNG hack is required!

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: There is one BIG catch: The background of the div HAS to be a solid color, and should match the colour of the pattern/gradient.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 thing to be covered in IE

For **IE10+**:

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#207cca 27%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 79%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#207cca 27%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 79%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
```

For **IE6-IE9**:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

I think it will be easy for you to replace the color codes.  I would also suggest you to take a look at [**ColorZilla**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for generating the CSS Gradient.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I know about gradients. Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

i dont think what you are saying is possible...because you have a **parent div** whose background is **gradient** and then you have an **inner div** whose background is **not transparent but black** (`#000000`) nou you have written **text on inner div** but want **font's background as gradient which is in parent div**...this is not posiible using css/css3 ...

now i can show you 2 ways (>=IE 9) by following which you can achieve same style with little alteration in your mark-up and css

**OPTION 1::**(need some photoshop work)

have a `<div>` set that `<div>`'s background black.then create gradient photoshop work(ex `.png`).now  set that image as a font/text background using `background-clip: text;`

```
webkit-background-clip: text;
-moz-background-clip: text;
background-clip: text;
```

**OPTION 2::** (above process is little time consuming ..there is another smarter way)

first have `div` with black background then write the text in inner div...set inner `div`'s background as gradient then use `-webkit-background-clip: text;-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`

for example ::

**MARK-UP**

```
 <div class="black">
   <div class="a">
      CAN YOU SEE THIS? THIS TEXT IS SUPPOSED TO TRANPARENT TO SHOW COLOR OF UNDERLYING DIV SO THAT IT LOOKS LIKE THE "HELLO WORLD" TEXT
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.black{
    background:black;
    overflow:hidden;
 }

.a{
background: #000000 -webkit-linear-gradient(red, green);
-webkit-background-clip: text;
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

**[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYYsj/3/)**

**[ALSO CHECK BROWSER COMPATIBILITY OF `background-clip` AT caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-clip)**

**OPTION 3::**(to make this style for IE8) (this process is simple,straight but not smart because it is IE specific)

create a photoshop work..make a text with gradient effect..now declare a div with black background..and include that image with `<img src="" />` tag . :)

Comment: This looks pretty good. I dont mind the SVG solution provided by apaul too . Anything that does not require me to download an external library like jQuery

Comment: obviously.. :) ... better solutions needs to come in sight first

Comment: Eh no need in waiting for better solutions because Ritabrata named your best options. The only one he missed was [css clipping/masking](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/), the latter of which requires you to get a little creative with an image editor of some sort.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000'); /* For < IE 7 */

-ms-filter : progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000'); /* For >= IE 8 */
```