# Using SVG logo as mask

Tags: svg, mask

I'm basing my exercise on the accepted answer in: [Creating transparent text to show gradient color of underlying div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712979/creating-transparent-text-to-show-gradient-color-of-underlying-div)

Here's my rendition in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skrln/zSjgL/

The svg code of my logo:

```
    <svg width="190" height="121">
        <mask id="cutouttext">
            <rect width="190" height="121" x="0" y="0" fill="white" />
                <path id="number-two" d="M75.3,56.1c7.3-3,14.2-12.5,14.2-24c0-17.7-15.1-32.1-36.8-32.1H0v121.5h52.4c30,0,43.4-16.5,43.4-36.8
    C95.8,72.3,87,59.8,75.3,56.1z M66.5,94.6h-49V79.7h0.1l27-22.1c3.5-2.8,5.3-6.1,5.3-9c0-4-3.2-7.6-8.4-7.6c-6.4,0-9.1,5.7-10.2,9
    l-14.6-3.9c2.9-10.8,11.8-19.1,25.2-19.1c14.4,0,24.5,9.4,24.5,21.5c0,12.4-9,18.1-17.1,23.8l-10.4,7.3h27.6V94.6z" />
                <polygon id="filler" points="190,33.9 190,0 101.6,0 101.6,121.5 190,121.5 190,87.6 141.4,87.6 141.4,74.7 177.1,74.7 177.1,46.6 
    141.4,46.6 141.4,33.9   " />
        </mask>
        <rect width="190" height="121" x="0" y="0" fill="white" mask="url(#cutouttext)" />
    </svg>
```

### The result so far:

[image: Starting point]

### Issue:

The mask isn't behaving the way I want to; I want the inner parts of the "B" and "E" to mask out the gray underlying div so you can see the background image like the image below:

[image: Goal]

I'm having trouble knowing what part of the logo is the  and which one is the . Also I can't seem to figure out the logic behind the `<mask>` in the SVG.

Comment: What exactly is your use case? You may not be able to get the exact effect you're after, but there may be a workable alternative.

Comment: I would like to see the body background image through the negative space of the logo. Regardless of how many 'layers' (in this case a div with gray background) are between the logo and body background.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your SVG. You placed it on a grey background, so the bits that are masked out are grey.

What you want to do is remove the grey background from below the SVG image. There may be neater ways of doing this, but one approach is to use a table layout with the logo in one cell and the grey background in another.

**[Here's a JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zSjgL/8/)**

### HTML

```
<div class="gray">
    <svg width="190" height="121">
        <mask id="cutouttext">
            <rect width="190" height="121" x="0" y="0" fill="white" />
            <path d="M75.3,56.1c7.3-3,14.2-12.5,14.2-24c0-17.7-15.1-32.1-36.8-32.1H0v121.5h52.4c30,0,43.4-16.5,43.4-36.8
    C95.8,72.3,87,59.8,75.3,56.1z M66.5,94.6h-49V79.7h0.1l27-22.1c3.5-2.8,5.3-6.1,5.3-9c0-4-3.2-7.6-8.4-7.6c-6.4,0-9.1,5.7-10.2,9
    l-14.6-3.9c2.9-10.8,11.8-19.1,25.2-19.1c14.4,0,24.5,9.4,24.5,21.5c0,12.4-9,18.1-17.1,23.8l-10.4,7.3h27.6V94.6z" />
            <polygon points="190,33.9 190,0 101.6,0 101.6,121.5 190,121.5 190,87.6 141.4,87.6 141.4,74.7 177.1,74.7 177.1,46.6 
    141.4,46.6 141.4,33.9   " />
        </mask>
        <rect width="190" height="121" x="0" y="0" fill="white" mask="url(#cutouttext)" />
    </svg>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.body {
    background: #550000 url('http://sciencelakes.com/data_images/out/7/8788677-red-background-wallpaper.jpg');
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0;
}
.gray {
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;
    height:121px;
}
.gray div, .gray svg {
    display:table-cell;
}
.gray div {
    background:gray;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for. I'm trying to make the SVG punch through everything except the background image. So no matter where the logo is placed (it's draggable in the jsfiddle), you would see through the gray background.

Comment: So you're looking for an SVG with some sort of `x-ray` attribute that can see through one background to another background behind it? No such thing, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was afraid for. Thanks for your help!